# На Linux пропадают USB-устройства после перезагрузки

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, usb

У меня имеется процессорная плата на ARM-процессоре rk-3288.
Есть сборка Debian для этого устройства с одной проблемой.
После перезагрузки пропадают USB устройства.

Если просто включаю устройство, то всё работает.
Делаю lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04e2:1410 Exar Corp. XR21V1410 USB-UART IC
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a89:0030
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2c7c:0125
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

А если перезагрузить (в любой момент), то ничто по USB не работает и lsusb уже выглядит так:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

И чтобы всё заработало нормально нужно выключить устройство, обесточить его и включить, тогда всё запускается без проблем. И если перезагрузить, то опять все USB пропадают.

В чём может быть проблема?
Что на это может влиять?
Можно ли как-то эти USB перезагружать уже после загрузки системы?

У меня есть одна конфигурация ядра для Ubuntu от производителя платы, где такой проблемы не наблюдается. Но там множество других проблем, которые решены в сборке, где лишь вот эта проблема с USB.

Comment: начните со сравнение содержимого кольцевого буфера сообщений программы linux в обоих случаях (программа *dmesg*).

Comment: [несколько из возможных причин — в ответах](https://serverfault.com/q/194991/292034)

Comment: USB VBUS не отрабатывает как надо? Включить устройства через внешний хаб?

Comment: Разница в строках у dmesg есть в момент когда USB не работают и когда они работают.
Но правда не понятно, что с этим делать.
И не работают не только USB, но и COM-порт, а также i2c-шина. Я так понимаю, потому, что это считается как USB-устройство.
Неизвестно, как перезагрузить все эти USB-устройства или увидеть ошибку хотя бы в каком-нибудь логе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл прекрасное решение своей проблемы!
Чтобы устройство перезагрузилось и USB работали после старта нужно его перезагрузить при помощи команды:

```
systemctl poweroff
```

Даже если устройство было перезагружено командой reboot, то после systemctl poweroff всё начинает работать безупречно.

P.S. По умолчанию устройство запускается автоматически после systemctl poweroff, а чтобы выключить его нужно использовать halt.